# Replace spaces with hyphens in a text document only on specific lines using regex

Tags: regex, osx-snow-leopard, textmate

I'm trying to replace spaces with hypens on all image links in my markdown text files. The image syntax is as follows:

`![image](Leadership-0910 Fulfilling the Vision-06-build-vision/06-build-vision-1.jpg "06-build-vision-1.jpg")`

As you can see there are some hypens between words and some spaces. I need them all to be hypens. However, as the documents contain other text I only want to remove the spaces on the lines starting with `![image]...`. I am using osx (10.6.8) and textmate, which allows me to find and replace using regex.

At the moment I can easily find all the lines using `^((\!\[([a-z]*)\]\())`

The problem I have is in how to replace the white spaces following with hypens?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Text→Filter Through Command (⌥⌘R)** to pipe the text through sed:

```
 sed '/^!\[image\]/s/ /-/g'
```

Not sure how you'd do it in pure TextMate, though.